# Firebase authentication and google-service.json

Tags: android, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I am new to Firebase. After reading Firebase doc, my understanding is that if I download `google-service.json` and drop it to Application folder of Android Studio project, the Firebase lib will do authentication under the hood so that I can access any of Firebase services `storage`, `database` etc.
I set Firebase Storage rule as allow only if client is authenticated
`allow read, write: if request.auth != null;`
But I am getting this error

```
User does not have permission to access this object.
```

If I remove `if request.auth != null` part, it works fine.

Could anyone help me to understand what is `google-service.json` for?

If this json is not for authentication, what is recommended authentication?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: request.auth mean user is login or not. It not mean that json file is present or not.
So uploading anything to firestore, please login user then do opertion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration data in `google-service.json` allows your Android app to find its Firebase project on Google's servers.

Given that the security rules are affecting whether your code works, it seems that your app can reach the project fine.

So the problem is not in connecting the app to the project, but in your code that signs the user in. It's impossible to say what is wrong, since you didn't share the code, but you'll want to check if there is a currently signed in user just before calling the Storage API:

```
if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null) {
  ... call to Storage here
}
```